# How cast from char* to T*?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ When should we prefer to use a two chained static_cast over reinterpret_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594395/c-when-should-we-prefer-to-use-a-two-chained-static-cast-over-reinterpret-cast)

Which is better?

```
static_cast<T *>(static_cast<void *>(buffer));
```

or

```
reinterpret_cast<T *>(buffer);
```

Where `buffer` is `char *` (memory chunk which contains values of type `T`).

Comment: maybe read first here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The chain of two `static_cast`s is better](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1863069/57428) - it is less implementation dependent.

Comment: Nice link, but note the first answer ends up stating that `reinterpret_cast` is also guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 4):

`reinterpret_cast` should be used to cast an integral type back to it's original type.  If the `char *` really originally was a `T *`, then `reinterpret_cast` will do the right thing.  If you are playing other games, then you should use `static_cast`

Comment: what about this case? Here I have something different than you told, I have a memory pool created this way `new char[size]` and there I'm creating objects of type T via placement operator new, and for determining the place where new object should be created I'm using `some_cast<T *>(buffer) + next_object_position` and this **some_cast** is what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 2):

Use reinterpret_cast because that's what you're doing conceptually.  static_cast is used when you expect the compiler will know how to do the conversion.  It's a safety mechanism because the compiler will generate an error if it doesn't actually know how to do it.  Reinterpret_cast is used when you want to say "trust me, the bits here are of this type."

Answer (score 1):

No one is better, the question is which one is less bad.

The `static_cast` is just guaranteed to work if the buffer really is a T. You can convert its address to a `void*` and back again. If it is of some other type, it is up to the implementation whether it works or not. Alignment issues is but one of the potential problems.

Using a `reinterpret_cast` is always implementation dependent. As such, it doesn't work any better, but at least it makes it obvious that this isn't portable code.

Therefore, I would use the `reinterpret_cast` here.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do that, `reinterpret_cast`. It's way more understandable than that `static_cast` dance.