# Proper way of casting pointer types

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

Considering the [following code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/19/420038.aspx) (and the fact that [`VirtualAlloc()` returns a `void*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
BYTE* pbNext = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(
    VirtualAlloc(NULL, cbAlloc, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
```

why is `reinterpret_cast` chosen instead of `static_cast`?

I used to think that `reinterpret_cast` is OK for e.g. casting pointers to and from integer types (like e.g. `DWORD_PTR`), but to cast from a `void*` to a `BYTE*`, isn't `static_cast` OK?

Are there any (subtle?) differences in this particular case, or are they just both valid pointer casts?

Does the C++ standard have a preference for this case, suggesting a way instead of the other?

Comment: In first place, I wouldn't assume that Microsoft developers follow "de facto good practices". `static_cast` is just fine here.

Comment: `static_cast` should be preferred, but some people prefer `reinterpret_cast` because the name shows what you are doing (you are reinterpreting the bit pattern).

Comment: (Anyway, +1, enjoy your `nice question` badge!)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

For **convertible pointers to fundamental types** both casts have the same meaning; so you are correct that `static_cast` is okay.

When converting between some pointer types, *it's possible that the specific memory address held in the pointer needs to change*.

That's where the two casts differ.  `static_cast` will make the appropriate adjustment.  `reinterpret_cast` will not.

For that reason, it's a good general rule to `static_cast` between pointer types unless you **know** that `reinterpret_cast` is desired.

Answer (score 33):

You should `static_cast`. **Use `static_cast` in cases where you're undoing an implicit conversion.**

In this particular case, however, there is no difference because you're converting from `void*`. But in general, `reinterpret_cast`ing between two object pointers is defined to be (§5.2.10/7):

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a diﬀerent type. When a prvalue `v` of type “pointer to `T1`” is converted to the type “pointer to cv `T2`”, **the result is `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))`** if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout types and the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`, or if either type is `void`. Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspeciﬁed.

Emphasis mine. Since `T1` for you is already `void*`, the cast to `void*` in `reinterpret_cast` does nothing. This is not true in general, which is what [Drew Dormann is saying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15579008/87234):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void print_pointer(const volatile T* ptr)
{
    // this is needed by oversight in the standard
    std::cout << static_cast<void*>(const_cast<T*>(ptr)) << std::endl;
}

struct base_a {};
struct base_b {};
struct derived : base_a, base_b {};

int main()
{
    derived d;

    base_b* b = &d; // implicit cast

    // undo implicit cast with static_cast
    derived* x = static_cast<derived*>(b);

    // reinterpret the value with reinterpret_cast
    derived* y = reinterpret_cast<derived*>(b);

    print_pointer(&d);
    print_pointer(x);
    print_pointer(y);
}
```

Output:

> 00CBFD5B
>   00CBFD5B
>   00CBFD5C

(Note that because `y` doesn't actually point to a `derived`, using it is undefined behavior.)

Here, `reinterpret_cast` comes up with a different value because it goes through `void*`. This is why you should use `static_cast` when you can, and `reinterpret_cast` when you have to.

Comment: Nice illustration!  Regarding `void*` conversion - I have this nagging recollection that *specifically* for conversions to/from `void*`, the standard allows `reinterpret_cast` to change the value.  And that only a cyclical conversion `X*` to `void*` to `X*` is guaranteed to preserve the address.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: @DrewDormann: I'm not sure I follow, which line are you referring to? For `reinterpret_cast`, all cases with `void*` (either as source type or destination type) go through the clause I quoted, so the only thing relevant from this point is `static_cast` w.r.t. `void*`. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: @GManNickG may I know your opinion on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725975/simple-c-pointer-casting) question? based on the answers here I think using 2 static here is safer but could you correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @GManNickG Can you explain the "..needed by oversight in the standard" part in `print_pointer`? Why not simply `cout` the `ptr`?

Comment: @User10482 I have long since forgotten, but if I were to guess it is/was probably missing a overload for `volatile`-qualified things. Totally unnecessary for this example to includes this, of course.

Answer (score 8):

Using `static_cast` to cast a pointer to and from `void*` is guaranteed to preserve the address.

`reinterpret_cast` on the other hand guarantees that if you cast the pointer from one type to other, and back to the original type, the address is preserved.

Although with most implementations, you would see the same results in using either of these, `static_cast` should be preferred.

And with `C++11` I remember that, using `reinterpret_cast` for `void*` has a well defined behavior. Before that this behavior was prohibited.

```
It is not permitted to use reinterpret_cast to convert between pointers to object type and pointers to void.
```

> Proposed resolution (August, 2010):
>
> Change 5.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast] paragraph 7 as follows:
>
> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of
>   a different type. When a prvalue v of type “pointer to T1” is
>   converted to the type “pointer to cv T2”, the result is **static_cast(static_cast(v))** if both T1 and T2 are standard-layout
>   types (3.9 [basic.types]) and the alignment requirements of T2 are no
>   stricter than those of T1, or if either type is void.
>
> Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to
>   T2” (where T1 and T2 are object types and where the alignment
>   requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1) and back to its
>   original type yields the original pointer value. The result of any
>   other such pointer conversion is unspecified.

More info [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1120).

Thanks to [Jesse Good](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906773/jesse-good) for the link.

Comment: Here is a [link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1120) about reinterpret cast, it was actually prohibited before C++11.