# Visual studio 2017 indent

Tags: c++, visual-studio, text-formatting

I installed visual studio 2017 professional and I have indent problem.

when I'm typing

```
void function(0, 0,
              1, 2);
```

and it's ok, but when I'm typing additional ( symbol I have this indent problem

```
void function(0, 0,
     (float)1, 2);
```

I changed setting inside Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->Indentation but can't get same indentation with additional '(' symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Old style C cast should not be used in c++ code (there are better alternatives available for casting). 
But in this case, you can just use literal float instead: (And you will killing two problems at one time)

```
void function(0, 0,
              1.f, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, So there is no way to use old C cast type without that indent problem right? :(

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, thanks for clarification, edited!

Comment: @Alatriste, honestly I'm not sure, I'm just giving you a workaround.

Comment: @Alatriste, maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578935/proper-way-of-casting-pointer-types  And: https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/2/28/c-casting-or-oh-no-we-broke-malloc

Comment: This isn't true. You can absolutely use C-style casts in C++, it's just not a good idea because there are better alternatives available.